# How can I join an object with arrays into a single array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is what I have (`wealthByDistribution`) and I require a solution like (`expectedArray`).

```js
const wealthByDistribution = {
  CheckingAccount: [
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 4,
      "value": 10
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 5,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 6,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 7,
      "value": 0
    }
  ],
  Company: [
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 4,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 5,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 6,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 7,
      "value": 110
    }
  ],
  InvestmentAccount: [
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 4,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 5,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 6,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 7,
      "value": 220
    }
  ],
  InvestmentInsurance: [
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 4,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 5,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 6,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 7,
      "value": 330
    }
  ],
  Loan: [
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 4,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 5,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 6,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 7,
      "value": 0
    }
  ],
  PassionAssets: [
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 4,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 5,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 6,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "month": 7,
      "value": 0
    }
  ]
}

const returnExpectedArray = (wealthByDistribution) => {
    const expectedArray = []
    return expectedArray
}

const expectedArray = [
    {
      "year": 2016,
      PassionAssets: 0,
      Loan: 0,
      InvestmentInsurance: 0,
      InvestmentAccount: 0,
      CheckingAccount: 10,
      Company: 0,
      "month": 4,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      PassionAssets: 0,
      Loan: 0,
      InvestmentInsurance: 0,
      InvestmentAccount: 0,
      CheckingAccount: 0,
      Company: 0,
      "month": 5,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      PassionAssets: 0,
      Loan: 0,
      InvestmentInsurance: 0,
      InvestmentAccount: 0,
      CheckingAccount: 0,
      Company: 0,
      "month": 6,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "year": 2016,
      PassionAssets: 0,
      Loan: 0,
      InvestmentInsurance: 330,
      InvestmentAccount: 220,
      CheckingAccount: 0,
      Company: 110,
      "month": 7,
      "value": 0
    }
]
```

Please if anyone can help me, I have been trying to solve it out for quite some time. I tried the following code, but it did not work as expected.

```js
const wealthByDistributionKeys = Object.keys(wealthByDistribution);
const [ key, ...rest ] = wealthByDistributionKeys;
const firstArray = wealthByDistribution[key] || [];

const expectedArray = firstArray.map((item, i) => {
    item[key] = item.value;
    return Object.assign({}, item, ...rest.map(r => {
        wealthByDistribution[r][i][r] = wealthByDistribution[r][i].value;
        return wealthByDistribution[r][i];
    }));
});
```

Comment: What's the reasoning behind the `Company` property value? The last object is expected to be `Company: 0,
      "month": 7,
      "value": 110`, is that really what you want? I'd have thought `Company: 110,
      "month": 7,
      "value": 0` would be more inline with the rest of the logic you appear to be doing (also, where does the `'value'` property value come from in the expected output objects?)

Comment: Yes you are rigth, Company: 110, "month": 7, "value": 0. My error structuring the expected result.

Comment: What does the `"value": 0` come from, then?

Comment: The value doesn't matter to me. I just need to concatenate the arrays and assign each property of the object to them as its value
For example 
const wealthByDistribution = {
    CheckingAccount: [
        {
            "year": 2016,
            "month": 4,
            "value": 10
        }
    ],
    Company: [
        {
            "year": 2016,
            "month": 4,
            "value": 0
        }
    ]
}
Expected result
const expected = [
    {
        "year": 2016,
        CheckingAccount: 10,
        Company: 0,
        "month": 4,
        "value": 10
    }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using corresponding keys, you could collect all value with year/month and get a combined result.

```js
const
    wealthByDistribution = { CheckingAccount: [{ year: 2016, month: 4, value: 10 }, { year: 2016, month: 5, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 6, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 7, value: 0 }], Company: [{ year: 2016, month: 4, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 5, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 6, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 7, value: 110 }], InvestmentAccount: [{ year: 2016, month: 4, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 5, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 6, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 7, value: 220 }], InvestmentInsurance: [{ year: 2016, month: 4, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 5, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 6, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 7, value: 330 }], Loan: [{ year: 2016, month: 4, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 5, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 6, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 7, value: 0 }], PassionAssets: [{ year: 2016, month: 4, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 5, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 6, value: 0 }, { year: 2016, month: 7, value: 0 }] },
    result = Object.values(Object
        .entries(wealthByDistribution)
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => {
            a.forEach(({ year, month, value }) => {
                const key = [year, month].join('|');
                r[key] ??= { year, month };
                r[key][k] = value;
            });
            return r;
        }, {})
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This results in `"Company": 110` in the last object, and no `value` in the output objects. I don't understand what OP is trying to do with those.

Comment: i don't either.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is just what I needed. You are amazing.